# Best Way to convert one Edmx Entity to one Business entity

Tags: entity-framework, orm, linq-to-entities

I am developing one application in which data is access from edmx entities and from that we have to fill each business entity after retriving data from edmx entity like:-

```
var tblproducts = tblproductsData
            .Select(t => new tblProduct()
                {
                    CategoryID = t.CategoryID,
                    Description = t.Description,
                    ID = t.ID,
                    Image = t.Image,
                    InsDt = t.InsDt,
                    Price = t.Price,
                    Quantity = t.Quantity,
                    Status = t.Status,
                    Title = t.Title,
                    tblCategory = new EFDbFirst.Models.tblCategory()
                        {
                            ID = t.tblCategory.ID,
                            status = t.tblStatus.StatusID,
                            Title_Category = t.tblCategory.Title_Category
                        },
                    tblStatu = new EFDbFirst.Models.tblStatu()
                        {
                            StatusDescription = t.tblStatus.StatusDescription
                            ,
                            StatusID = t.tblStatus.StatusID
                        }
                });
```

I am fadeup with this because everytime i have to convert one to another while getting data and setting data in db,
Is there any good way to create some common mehod which takes one  anonymous type and converts it to another anonymous type.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Your example isn't that clear.

First of all, EF doesn't work with anonymous types inside itself, it works with the EF types you have defined either using edmx file or code first. You can however create anonymous types yourself by defining an Select statement.

E.g:

```
var products = context.tblProductsData
               .Select(r => new { Description = r.Description }); //new without typename is an 
                                                                  //anonymous object
```

The tblProduct, tblCategory and tblStatu objects, are they EF types? If so, you don't need to write a Select, EF will generate objects for you when you execute it.

E.g:

```
var products = context.tblProductsData.ToList();
```

This will automatically generate tblProduct objects for you. When you try to navigate to tblProduct.tblCategory or tblProduct.tblStatu, lazy loading will retrieve them for you. If you want to explicit load them during first query (eager-loading) use the `Include` function.

E.g:

```
var products = context.tblProductsData.Include(r => r.tblCategory)
                                      .Include(r => r.tblStatu).ToList();
```

However if tblProducts, tblCategory and tblStatu is business objects and NOT EF types, there isn't any other way to do this, you have to explicit create them in a Select statement.